# Cookies intval

Tags: php

Не работает код постоянно пишет что ставим куку!

```
$check = !empty($_COOKIE['_ws']) ? intval($_COOKIE['_ws']) : false;
if(isset($check) && $check > 0){
    // Кука установлена
    // Можно проверять её значение или делать еще что-то
    if(date("d.m.Y",$check) == date("d.m.Y")){
        echo 'Вы уже отправляли!';
        $good1 = false;
    }
} else {
    // Кука не установлена
    // Ставим её
    setcookie ("_ws","$times",time()+86400,"/");
    echo "ставим куку";
    $good1 = true; // *Если переменная служит для для определения именно установки куки, а не её существования
}
```

Comment: @big-vl, а зачем вам тут кука ?

Comment: А что такое: $times и где оно определено ?

Comment: Да код-то в общем-то рабочий, хотя и из раздела "где тут кнопка "развидеть"?". Подозреваю, что глюк исключительно в хроме. Добавьте строчку

    header("Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

и всё будет ок.

Comment: intval это вообще php 4 какой то . Фтопку такое.

Comment: ну если intval в топку то чем и как заменить???

Comment: @big-vl, (int) перед переменной.

Comment: @vkovalchuk88, хотя бы выяснили в чем отличие `(int)` от `intval()`, прежде чем рассуждать о версиях PHP.

Comment: @Равнодушный, я уже больше 10 лет в PHP, в чем разница в вашем примере? Ловите минус.

Comment: @vkovalchuk88, ну вопрос все-таки не мой...) Так что зря новичка обидели...) 10 лет назад, судя по нику, Вы еще только 9ый класс заканчивали, а информатика в те времена лишь в 10ом начиналась. Так что читайте мануалы, прежде чем чушь нести.

Comment: Мне в 99 году дайлап провели, какая инфморматика? Сайты делал уже тогда. Чушь это ты мелешь, браток. intval использовался во времена php 4, ты тоже пишешь код 10 летней давности? :-) переучивайся.http://www.presidentofrussia.ru/mini/24666.html вот тут в каталоге остался сайт который я больше 10 лет назад делал. Полифонические мелодии midi mmf, знаешь что это? Еще не родился тогда))

Comment: @vkovalchuk88,

    var_dump(intval('A', 16)); //int (10)
    var_dump((int)'A'); //int (0)

иди учись.

Comment: @vkovalchuk88, так и хочеться выразиться! Какое PHP4? Вы сударь в мануалы давно заглядывали или про то, что intval() уже своё отжило вместе с PHP4, вам во дворе пацаны нашептали? О каких 10-ти года идет речь? Курсы Попова Женьки за 10 часов прошли и в ассы записали себя? Зла не хватает!

Comment: header("Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ ОТВЕТ!!!

Answer (score 1):

Немного переписал код, выполняет в общем-то тоже самое. И даже работает. Только логика другая.

```
<?php
    $good1 = false; //Пусть будет
    if (isset($_COOKIE['_ws'])) { //Если кука существует, значит отправляли
        echo 'Вы уже отправляли!';
    }
    else {
        $midnight = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day"))); //Ближайшая полночь
        setcookie('_ws', '1', $midnight, "/"); //Ставим куку
        $good1 = true;
        echo "ставим куку";
    }
```

Comment: Забыл IntVal впихнуть.

Comment: Уговорил... Куда же без `intval()`...

    if (1 === intval(isset($_COOKIE['_ws']))) { /* ... */ }

Comment: @Равнодушный,  о теперь гармонично выглядит, настояще PoHaPэ школоло едишн, кокой молодэц, толко дорогой надо было написать IntVal!

Comment: @vkovalchuk88, забавных троллей плодят на улице Энтузиастов...

Comment: @Равнодушный, я прост дарагой мой хатэл сказать, что за вами чистить код не хватает рук. 

Ищо один быдло кодерщик:-) @Deonis, используйте дальше свои говнофункции, все равно нам платят нормально, чтобы мы за вас  все переделывали:-)

Comment: @vkovalchuk88, это вы [тут посоветуете][1]. И не забудьте добавить, чтоб они нубы вычеркнули функцию из PHP5 и дописали что она уже давно **deprecated**. Потому, как ваш мозг ракушки кипит от негодования.

   [1]:http://us3.php.net/manual/ru/function.intval.php

Comment: @Deonis, мой сладенький, такими темпами можно очень много функций повыключать, это единственный большой недостаток, PHP что он так медленно развивается. 

Мозг ваще не кипит, мой дарагой.

Comment: @vkovalchuk88, боюсь представить, что же вы там переделываете, если из всего страха конструкции


    $check = !empty($_COOKIE['_ws']) ? intval($_COOKIE['_ws']) : false;
    if(isset($check) && $check > 0){ }


прицепились к ни в чем не повинной функции, исправно выполняющей свою работу.

Comment: @Deonis, не поддавайтесь на провокацию. Функция `boolval()` появилась только в `php5.5`, так что функции типа {TYPE}val() еще долго будут выносить мозг бедному идеальному кодеру, который так измучился за нами все переделывать...